# Java post json data

Tags: java, json, http, post

I want to make a function sending a post request with `JSON` data

I would like to do something like:

```
    public Service() throws Exception {
        CommunicationService c = new CommunicationService();
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("email");
        list.add("test@email.com");
        list.add("password");
        list.add("testPassword");
        c.post("https://discordapp.com/api/auth/login", list);
    }
```

Communication service class

```
public class CommunicationService {
    public void post(String url, List<String> params) {

        // WHAT I ASK YOU

        // I want to do the post request on URL

        for (int i = 0; i < params.size(); i++)
        {
            // params name in i index from list and value in i + 1
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void saveToUrl(String myURL, List<MyObject> myParams) throws IOException
    {
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(myURL);
        List<MyObject> params = myParams;
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("task", "savemodel"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("code", generatedJSONString));
        CloseableHttpResponse response = null;
        Scanner in = null;
        try
        {
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            response = httpClient.execute(post);
            // System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            in = new Scanner(entity.getContent());
            while (in.hasNext())
            {
                System.out.println(in.next());

            }
            EntityUtils.consume(entity);
        } finally
        {
            in.close();
            response.close();
        }
    }
```